# Install Ubuntu to a hard drive partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

(currently running windows)
I have a 3TB USB hard drive called **GIGA** I have created a new, 3GB, (currently unallocated) partition on it.

I want to install ubuntu to *just* the new partition, without touching the rest of **GIGA**.

I tried creating a new drive in the partition, I gave it the letter `U` and the label **UBUNTU**, but rufus refused to read it as a seperate drive, and insisted on wiping the whole of **GIGA**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do it seems is: make a bootable Partition using an ISO and RUFUS.

Basically, you use rufus to make a pendrive bootable, boot from the pendrive by changing settings in your BIOS and then fololow jawtheshark`s post.

Steps:
Rufus-> select ISO-> Use ISO Method-> Make pendrive bootable->Boot from the pendrive->Install ubuntu to the Partition.

Also, 3 GB is not sufficient for Ubuntu. You need minimum 5 GB.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

You are skipping a step.

Comment: I think you need to do a lot of research before doing it. Cause missteps could cause a serious data loss. Please back up.

Answer (score 0):

During installation, you should see [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KURnS.png).  Couldn't you select `Something Else`?  Because that's what you need to do if you want to reuse your pre-partitioned disk.

Next screen, you select your 3GB partition.  Click `Change..`, then set it to format to `ext4` and the mount point `/`.  When you continue the installation, it will most likely complain about having no swap space, but you can ignore that (it's not ideal, but you can ignore it)  Obviously, make absolutely sure that you selected the partition you want.  Any other and you might lose data.

Comment: 3GB is going to be a bit on the short side.  It may be that's why the installer wouldn't install Ubuntu.  I wouldn't use a partition less than 10G.